# Configure keys in erlang shell on linux

Tags: linux, erlang

All!
Is it possible to configure Home,End, Del key in Erlang shell under Linux.

At the moment when I press Home, it generate 'H' and when End - 'F'...

Comment: This question does not belong on superuser. The Erlang shell is notoriously bad with such key combinations, so I would say it's more related to the Erlang programming environment. For example, even though they are configured correctly in the OS X Terminal.app the Erlang shell still doesn't care (the Python shell handles this nicely).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it is to start the Erlang shell with `rlwrap -a erl`.  `rlwrap` is a utility that puts the `readline` library between the user and the underlying program, giving features such as familiar key bindings, history search, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks eshells tab completion.